# Why do buttons not work between specific div tags using the same classes?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, dom, twitter-bootstrap-3

For some reason, buttons don't work when they are inside specific HTML tags. They can't be clicked, even when:
a. the classes applied are exactly the same as the buttons that do work, and b. the tags that they are in are also exactly the same as the ones that do work. Commented examples below:

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <h3 class="text-left">The European What?</h3>
              <h4 class="text-left">The European Union</p>
              <p class="text-left">A bunch of important people from different countries gathered and thought it would be productive to work together. So now in Europe there are 28 countries that act like they’re one.</p>
              <!-- This button works -->
              <button class="btn lesson-toc" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="material-icons icon-align">list</i>Table of Contents</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<section id="lesson" style="position:relative;overflow-y:scroll" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#toc">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- This button doesn't work -->
        <button class="btn lesson-toc" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
          <i class="material-icons icon-align">list</i>
        </button>
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
          <h5>How was the EU Formed? This is very long.</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- This button works -->
    <button class="btn lesson-toc" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      <i class="material-icons icon-align">list</i>
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out it was that the .lesson-toc class had a CSS property of position: absolute; and the z-index was pushing it below something else so it became unclickable. It was only broken in that specific div because in the other ones, there was nothing of higher z-index value to cover it.